# Find the path of a node X from the root of the tree

Tags: tree, prolog, nodes

I want to ask your help about a program I want to code in Prolog. I want to make a function `path(X,tree,Path)` that finds the path of node X from the root of the tree. Basically, I thought that there will be three sentences.

1. `path(X, void, [])`, return empty list because there is no tree
2. `path(X,tree(X,void,void),[X])`, return a list that contains the element of the tree root
3. `path(X,tree(Route,Left,Right),Path)`, **?????????**

I believe there are 3 sentences, I know the 2 of them but I don't know what is the third. Can anyone help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

your clause 3) should add in front of returned path the current node, and recurse on branch

```
path(X, tree(Route, Left, Right), [Route|Path]) :-
  path(X, Left, Path) ; path(X, Right, Path).
```

Note the disjunction (`;`)/2. The rule will try first Left and, on backtracking, the Right branch.

Answer (score -1):

Your rule works only in this case:

?- path(3,tree(1,tree(2,void,void),tree(3,void,void)),X).
X = [1, 3].
- there are three nodes in the tree.

but if I try to add more nodes in the tree it doesn't work. Look the example below:
?- path(7,tree(1,tree(2,4,5),tree(3,6,7)),X).
false.
The answer must be X = [1,3,7].

Comment: This is not an answer. As long as your reputation doesn't allow you to leave comments, edit or comment on your original question.

Comment: tree(3,6,7) is not a valid tree node according to your specification.

Comment: why is not valid? What is the valid tree? Can you give me an example which you believe that the 3) rule is correct so I can examine it?

Comment: I give you something better, a predicate that tests for valid trees: `is_tree(void).  is_tree(tree(_,L,R)) :- is_tree(L), is_tree(R).`